# Discord.net Custom RPC goes to me and not the bot

Tags: c#, discord.net, discord-rpc

I'm trying to give my bot a custom RPC, but it shows up on my profile instead of the bots.
I use a library called NetDiscordRpc, here's my code, i have no idea why this happens.

```cs
using NetDiscordRpc;
using NetDiscordRpc.RPC;

[...]

peivate void UpdateRPC()
{
   client = new DiscordRPC("My bots client ID");

   //Subscribe to events
   client.OnReady += (sender, e) =>
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Received Ready from user {0}", e.User.Username);
   };

   client.OnPresenceUpdate += (sender, e) =>
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Received Update! {0}", e.Presence);
   };

   //Connect to the RPC
   client.Initialize();

            

   client.SetPresence(new RichPresence()
   {
      //Setting custom RPC details

   });

  client.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Bots can't have Rich Presence

Comment: But i saw other bots had custom statuses? Like "*Playing* !help" or stuff like that

Comment: That's not Rich Presence That's activities, which you don't need a separate package for. That can be set using Discord.Net

Comment: You can refer to the [documentation](https://discordnet.dev/api/Discord.WebSocket.BaseSocketClient.html#Discord_WebSocket_BaseSocketClient_SetActivityAsync_Discord_IActivity_)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems like discord doesn't support RPC for bots. What I was looking for was activities.
Thank you Anu6is!

Edit: Typo.